# Use node.js fs with Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, google-visualization, babeljs

I'm doing the following in a js file

```
    var FS = require('fs');
    var TestGoogle = eval(FS.readFileSync('../loader.js', 'utf8'));
```

I added to my webpack config:

```
node: {
  fs: "empty"
}
```

The webpack compiles with Babel but I get an error in the js console

```
FS.readFileSync is not a function
```

Why is this? I would simply like to import a javascript file. Specifically in order to use material bar charts of google. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#creating-material-bar-charts

In vanilla js, I need to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
```

And then, as the tutorial states, use google.charts.Bar instead of google.visualization.BarChart. Unfortunately, I can't get this simple vanilla JS to play nicely with Node.js, Babel, Webpack.

Comment: You want fs and nodejs, yet you want to import charts in the same nodejs? I don't quite get it

Answer (score 2):

Try add `target: 'node'` to webpack.config.js. I had the same problem and it solved for me.

Comment: I tried this, but no luck. I have similar problem like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608118/uncaught-typeerror-fs-readfilesync-is-not-a-function